# replace underscore with dash using url rewrite module of iis

Tags: asp.net, url, web-config, url-rewriting

I have issue regarding Url rewrite module.

I want to implement permanent redirect (301) into my site. and url is, I want to permanently redirect

http://demo.datadiary.com/search/product/ahmedabad/ac_dealers

url to

http://demo.datadiary.com/search/product/ahmedabad/ac-dealers

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `I have issue` what is the issue??? and seems you forget to ask the ***problem*** you having !!!

Comment: I have already asked that I can't able to do 301 redirect. And that is the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution. put the following into your web.config, but keep in mind that your host must have installed Url rewrite module in iis.

```
<rule name="Imported Rule 1-2" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(search/product/ahmedabad.*/[^/]*?)_([^/_]*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}-{R:2}" redirectType="Permanent" />
                </rule>
```

Comment: How do you do it if you have `~/search_products/items_list.aspx` both directory and page name?