# regex to replace one word in url - 301 Redirect using URL Rewrite IIS asp.net

Tags: asp.net, regex, iis-7.5, url-rewrite-module

I want to set up a 301 redirect for

`mysite.com/banana                mysite.com/fruit`

`mysite.com/banana/yellow         mysite.com/fruit/yellow`

`mysite.com/banana/yellow/sale    mysite.com/fruit/yellow/sale`

(The words "yellow" and "sale" could be replaced with anything, they are variables in a route.)

This works for the first case, but not the others:

```
<rule name="banana" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="banana" />
  <action type="Redirect" url="fruit" />
</rule>
```

Based on this question:
[replace underscore with dash using url rewrite module of iis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14278041/replace-underscore-with-dash-using-url-rewrite-module-of-iis)

This works for the third case only:

```
<rule name="banana" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(mysite.com.*/[^/]*?)banana/([^/_]*)/([^/_]*)$" />
  <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}fruit/{R:2}/{R:3}" />
</rule>
```

What I need is a regex that returns

{R:1} mysite.com/

{R:2} /yellow/sale

or

{R:1} mysite.com/

{R:2}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not keep it simple?

```
<match url="mysite.com/banana(/.+)*$" />
<action type="Redirect" url="mysite.com/fruit{R:1}" />
```

Or if you only want to go two levels deep:

```
<match url="mysite.com/banana((?:/[^/]+){0,2})$" />
<action type="Redirect" url="mysite.com/fruit{R:1}" />
```

Comment: There might be a subtle error in the first regex--when I test it the substitution doesn't happen for the first two samples

Comment: It was on my end, my test tool wasn't handling the $ well. Sorry

Answer (score 1):

How about the following:

```
<rule name="banana" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="mysite.com/banana(.+)?" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="mysite.com/fruit{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

Comment: This works for me also, I just marked one as the answer since it was answered first. Thanks!